# EPPlus multi-threading gets "out of memory" exception

Tags: multithreading, memory, out-of-memory, epplus

I was trying to parallelize EPPlus by using multi-threading. I tried to spawn 20 threads with each thread generating 1000 sheets with 10 column and 26 rows. The program consumed memory up to 1.8GB and threw an "out of memory" exception.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: As a shot in the dark, is your program compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It's compliled for "Any CPU", but I am running it on a 32bit OS. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code? There's not enough information to come up with other suggestions.

Comment: I have posted my code below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program that I tried to do it in multi-thread, but I got an "out of memory" exception:

```
               class Program
                {
                    private static int fileID=0;
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        List<Thread> threadPool = new List<Thread>();
                        int threadCount = 20;


                        for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++)
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread reportThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => GenerateThousandSheets());
                            threadPool.Add(reportThread);
                            reportThread.Start();
                        }

                        threadPool.ForEach(x => x.Join());
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }


                    private static void GenerateThousandSheets()
                    {
                        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample6.xlsx");
                        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

                        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                        for(int x= 0;x<1000;x++)
                        {
                            int newPosition = ws.Index + x;
                            pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("Template","Sheet"+x);
                        }

                        FileInfo outputFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName +fileID+ "-output.xlsx");
                        pck.SaveAs(outputFile);
                        counter++
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is 32 bit, then a single executable can use, at most, 2GB.
In fact, 1.8GB is really near this threshold.
Use 64bit OS with more RAM on your machine or spawn less thread or use less thread when you use Paralle.ForEach using different processor affinity